# Download Images from list of urls

Tags: image, google-chrome

I have a list of urls in a text file.i want the images to be downloaded to a particular folder ,how i can do it.is there any addons available in chrome or any other program to download images from url

Answer (score 90, accepted):

- Create a folder in your machine.
- Place your text file of images URL in the folder.
- `cd` to that folder.
- Use `wget -i images.txt`
- You will find all your downloaded files in the folder.

Comment: Perfect ! one more advantage of using Linux

Comment: Beware that in Windows when launching wget from Powershell, wget will be aliased by an internal Windows command which will behave slightly differently. If you need to use the original wget just open a normal cmd.exe shell and launch it from there.

Comment: I had to `brew install wget` first, but after that, this was a breeze! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 9):

On Windows 10/11 this is fairly trivial using

```
for /F "eol=;" %f in (filelist.txt) do curl -O %f
```

Note the inclusion of `eol=;` allows us to mask individual exclusions by adding `;` at the start of those lines in filelist.txt that we do not want this time. If using above in a batch file GetFileList.cmd then double those %%'s

So in my system I simply **type and enter `Do GetFileList`** and all those stored URLs are downloaded, where `Do` is an old DO'S trick to keep many small commands in one self editing zip file but nowadays I use CMD where `Do Edit` calls it up as `Notepad "%~f0"` to paste a section like this.

Part of Do.bat

```
:GetFileList
Rem as posted to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42878196
for /F "eol=;" %%f in (filelist.txt) do curl -O %%f
exit /b 0
goto error GetFileList
```

Windows 7 has a FTP command, but that can often throw up a firewall dialog requiring a User Authorization response.

Currently running Windows 7 and wanting to download a list of URLs without downloading any wget.exe or other dependency like curl.exe (which would be simplest as the first command) the shortest compatible way is a power-shell command (not my favorite for speed, but if needs must.)

The file with URLs is `filelist.txt` and `IWR` is the PS near equivalent of `wget`.

The Security Protocol first command ensures we are using modern TLS1.2 protocol

`-OutF ... split-path ...` means the filenames will be the same as remote filenames but in CWD (current working directory), for scripting you can `cd /d folder` if necessary.

```
PS> [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = "Tls12" ; GC filelist.txt | % {IWR $_ -OutF $(Split-Path $_ -Leaf)}
```

To run as a CMD use a slightly different set of quotes around `'Tls12'`

```
PowerShell -C "& {[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 'Tls12' ; GC filelist.txt | % {IWR $_ -OutF $(Split-Path $_ -Leaf)}}"
```

Answer (score 3):

This needs to be made into a function with error handling but it repeatedly downloads images for image classification projects

```py
    import requests

    urls = pd.read_csv('cat_urls.csv') #save the url list as a dataframe

    rows = []

    for index, i in urls.iterrows():
        rows.append(i[-1])

    counter = 0

    for i in rows:
    

    file_name = 'cat' + str(counter) + '.jpg'
    
        print(file_name)
        response = requests.get(i)
        file = open(file_name, "wb")
        file.write(response.content)
        file.close()
        counter += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import time
import sys
import urllib
from progressbar import ProgressBar

def get_raw_html(url):
    version = (3,0)
    curr_version = sys.version_info
    if curr_version >= version:     #If the Current Version of Python is 3.0 or above
        import urllib.request    #urllib library for Extracting web pages
        try:
            headers = {}
            headers['User-Agent'] = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.27 Safari/537.17"
            request = urllib.request.Request(url, headers = headers)
            resp = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
            respData = str(resp.read())
            return respData
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
    else:                        #If the Current Version of Python is 2.x
        import urllib2
        try:
            headers = {}
            headers['User-Agent'] = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.27 Safari/537.17"
            request = urllib2.Request(url, headers = headers)
            try:
                response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
            except URLError: # Handling SSL certificate failed
                context = ssl._create_unverified_context()
                response = urlopen(req,context=context)
            #response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
            raw_html = response.read()
            return raw_html    
        except:
            return"Page Not found"


def next_link(s):
    start_line = s.find('rg_di')
    if start_line == -1:    #If no links are found then give an error!
        end_quote = 0
        link = "no_links"
        return link, end_quote
    else:
        start_line = s.find('"class="rg_meta"')
        start_content = s.find('"ou"',start_line+1)
        end_content = s.find(',"ow"',start_content+1)
        content_raw = str(s[start_content+6:end_content-1])
        return content_raw, end_content


def all_links(page):
    links = []
    while True:
        link, end_content = next_link(page)
        if link == "no_links":
            break
        else:
            links.append(link)      #Append all the links in the list named 'Links'
            #time.sleep(0.1)        #Timer could be used to slow down the request for image downloads
            page = page[end_content:]
    return links

def download_images(links, search_keyword):

    choice = input("Do you want to save the links? [y]/[n]: ")
    if choice=='y' or choice=='Y':
        #write all the links into a test file. 
        f = open('links.txt', 'a')        #Open the text file called links.txt
        for link in links:
            f.write(str(link))
            f.write("\n")
        f.close()   #Close the file 
    num = input("Enter number of images to download (max 100): ")
    counter = 1
    errors=0
    search_keyword = search_keyword.replace("%20","_")
    directory = search_keyword+'/'
    if not os.path.isdir(directory):
        os.makedirs(directory)
    pbar = ProgressBar()
    for link in pbar(links):
        if counter<=int(num):
            file_extension = link.split(".")[-1]
            filename = directory + str(counter) + "."+ file_extension
            #print ("Downloading image: " + str(counter)+'/'+str(num))
            try:
                urllib.request.urlretrieve(link, filename)
            except IOError:
                errors+=1
                #print ("\nIOError on Image" + str(counter))
            except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
                errors+=1
                #print ("\nHTTPError on Image"+ str(counter))
            except urllib.error.URLError as e:
                errors+=1
                #print ("\nURLError on Image" + str(counter))

        counter+=1
    return errors


def search():

    version = (3,0)
    curr_version = sys.version_info
    if curr_version >= version:     #If the Current Version of Python is 3.0 or above
        import urllib.request    #urllib library for Extracting web pages
    else:
        import urllib2 #If current version of python is 2.x

    search_keyword = input("Enter the search query: ")

    #Download Image Links
    links = []
    search_keyword = search_keyword.replace(" ","%20")
    url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=' + search_keyword+ '&espv=2&biw=1366&bih=667&site=webhp&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=XosDVaCXD8TasATItgE&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAg'
    raw_html =  (get_raw_html(url))
    links = links + (all_links(raw_html))
    print ("Total Image Links = "+str(len(links)))
    print ("\n")
    errors = download_images(links, search_keyword)
    print ("Download Complete.\n"+ str(errors) +" errors while downloading.")

search()
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack over flow! Usually to make it more accessible you can add some text to describe and explained what the code is doing ;)

Answer (score 0):

In this [python project](https://github.com/adriano-pinaffo/download_images) I make a search in unsplash.com, which brings me a list of URL, then I save a number of them (pre-defined by the user) to a pre-defined folder. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, `install wget - https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/wget/1.11.4-1/`

and add `C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin` to your environment path.

create a folder with a txt file of all the images you want to download.

in the location bar at the top of the file explorer type `cmd`

When the command prompt opens enter the following.

`wget -i images.txt --no-check-certificate`